# How to pass Latitude and Longitude from database to Google Maps Activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I've set up a database which through a textview displays the latitude and longitude of a specific building. There is a "go" button underneath which loads up my mapsActivity. However, I can't seem to get the lat and long to be placed on the map.

Maps Activity

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker, map1, map2, map3, map4, map5, map6, map7;
    ZoomControls zoom;
   // public static String TAG1;
   // public static String TAG2;
   public static String TAG_LAT = "lat";
    public static String TAG_LNG = "lng";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        ToggleButton b1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Queen's Building Search");

        Intent intent = getIntent();








        mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);

        zoom = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zcZoom);
        zoom.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());

            }
        });
        zoom.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());

            }
        });



      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
            double value = extras.getDouble("Latitude");
            double value1 = extras.getDouble("Longitude");
           //  TAG_LAT = extras.getString("Latitude");
           // TAG_LNG = extras.getString("Longitude");
           goToLocation(value, value1);


        }
```

Go to location Method being called

```
public void goToLocation(double lat, double lng) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll);
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);
       // btnGo();



    }
```

building activity

```
btnGoLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Double lat = selectedBuilding.getLatitude();
            Double lng = selectedBuilding.getLongitude();


            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
           // Intent intent = new Intent(BuildingActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
            //Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            Intent intent = new Intent(BuildingActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
            bundle.putDouble(MapsActivity.TAG_LNG,lat);
            bundle.putDouble(MapsActivity.TAG_LNG, lng);


          //  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
          //  intent.putExtra("Latitude", +lat);
          //  intent.putExtra("Longitude", ""+lng);






           // intent.putExtra("latitude", lat);
           // intent.putExtra("longitude", lng);

           intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);



            // Double latt=extras.getDouble(lat);
            //Double loNg=extras.getDouble(lng)
        }
    });
```

As you can see my code is pretty messy trying to get this to work. If anyone could teamview with me it'd be a lot easier to show what i'm trying to do. I feel like i'm close.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try in your MapActivity:

```
intent.getDoubleExtra("Latitude", 0);
```

?

Edit: and by the way, it isn't a database... just intent between 2 activities. No persistence here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in `BuildingActivity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Latitude", ""+lat);
                intent.putExtra("Longitude", ""+lng);
```

In `MapsActivity` get this value in `onCreate()` callback using this way...

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

If your extra data is represented as strings, then you can use intent.getStringExtra(String name) method. In your case:

```
String lat = intent.getStringExtra("Latitude");
String lng = intent.getStringExtra("Longitude");
```

Now you have both lat and lng value in your `MapsActivity`.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! I have the lat and long in the database set up as double. It's coming up that lat and lng are never being used?

Comment: try this code : 
latitudeName.setText(lat);
        longitudeName.setText(lng);

Comment: I've updated the OP to show exactly what's trying to happen. Do you think you know how to fix? it loads up the MapsActivity but the google map is blank however :(